# Could HMAC output be the same for different key and message pairs

Tags: cryptography, hmac

Could the output of the HMAC be the same if I used different keys and messages?

Example:

```
Out1 = HMAC(key1, msg1)
Out2 = HMAC(key2, msg2)
```

Could Out1=Out2 under any condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short**, you can't find such pairs better than negligible probability when the search is computationally bounded.

---

HMAC is a Pseudo-Random Function (PRF) under the assumption that the used hash function is PRF.

What you are looking for a collision for the HMAC. In theory, it is possible to find such pairs that they will collide.

If you use a `n` bit output then the collision probability of two pairs is `1/2^n` for the fixed key. If HMAC is initiated with SHA256 then the collision of two random pairs will be `1/2^256`. By the birthday paradox, you will need around `2^128` pairs to find a collision with 50% under the same key.

A similar calculation can be performed with random keys, too.

Comment: I think the question assumes that we control both the key and input to HMAC. This is technically outside the PRF security model. For HMAC it turns out that it's very easy to find equivalent keys and create collisions as requested.

Comment: I did not read it this way otherwise I it would be msg1 in both cases.

Comment: That’s still fine right since the requirement is that key and message pairs are distinct?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually **yes**! >ou can create such collisions, and they are very easy to find. For a proof, see this python snippet:

```py
import hmac

m1 = b"PAYLOAD"
m2 = m1

key1 = b"PADDING\x00"
key2 = b"PADDING"

out1 = hmac.new(key1, m1, "sha256").digest()
out2 = hmac.new(key2, m2, "sha256").digest()
print(key1 == key2) # Different keys
print(out1 == out2) # same digest
```

The example above shows different key-message pairs producing the same output.

The reason for this is in the design of HMAC itself, and keys of different lengths are processed. See [Step 1 of HMAC description in section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104).

**Is this an issue?** In practice? No, since in the proper usage of HMAC as a MAC or a PRF, the key is randomly chosen and has usually a fixed size. An attacker doesn't have the same luxury as we had in the code above. In theory? It could be in a case where you are trying to formally prove your protocol and rely on the fact that these collisions are hard to find even if the attacker controls both the key and the input.